# How to draw curvy arrow at the edge of a cylinder

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I would like to draw a figure similar to the attached here. What I ended up with is the following figure. I use the code:

```
a = Graphics3D[{Opacity[.8], EdgeForm[], Cyan, 
    Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.1}}, 0.8]}, Boxed -> False, 
   ImageSize -> Large, ViewPoint -> Above];
b = Graphics3D[{Red, 
    Arrow /@ 
     Table[{0.8 {Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0}, { Cos[θ], 
        Sin[θ], 0}}, {θ, 0, 2 π, π/15}]}, 
   Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Above];
Show[a, b]
```

This gives me the output as follows (without the hand-made curved arrow below): 
[image]

Is there any way to make these arrows curvy? Instead of plain arrows, is it possible to draw curved arrows as shown in the figure. The curve may be similar to a sine or cosine (periodic) curve, for example (a hand-made example is shown below the figure).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Posters might want to create a `CurvyArrow` function with the following interface: `CurvyArrow[ {startpoint, endpoint}, {offsetstart, offsetend},polarization]`, with given start and end points, an offset in position as given by the builtin `Arrow`, and a polarization parameter specifying the plane in which the wiggly line should reside (maybe via the normal vector to said plane?). That should be fairly general and useful to many readers. I would also call that `PhotonArrow`. Hey, I hope you don't expect *me* to do all the work!

Answer (score 8):

```
pts = Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π, π/4}];
Graphics[{Arrow[BSplineCurve[pts]]}]
```

[image]

For you then:

```
z = 0.09;
c = Table[{0.03 Sin[20 ϕ], ϕ, 0.05}, {ϕ, 0.8, 1.1, 
    0.01}];
d = RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 0, 1}];
e = Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0], Red, 
    Arrow[BSplineCurve[
      Table[c.d, {θ, 0, 2 π, π/15}]]]}];
a = Graphics3D[{Opacity[.8], EdgeForm[], Cyan, 
    Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.1}}, 0.8]}, Boxed -> False, 
   ImageSize -> Large, ViewPoint -> Above];
b = Graphics3D[{Red, 
    Arrow /@ 
     Table[{1.1 {Cos[θ + z], Sin[θ + z], 0}, 
       1.2 {Cos[θ + z], Sin[θ + z], 0}}, {θ, 0, 
       2 π, π/15}]}, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Above];
Show[a, e, b]
```

[image]

Comment: I guess he wanted the little red arrows to be 'photon-like'.

Comment: Ahhh, right, I'll see if I can get that, but he seems to have buggered off himself.

Comment: Yes Peltio. You are right. I want that red arrows to appear as a curvy arrows, just a photon-like radiation coming out from the cylinder. Thanks Feyre for your help.

Comment: @Priyam
Edited my answer. This should more or less be it then.

Comment: @Feyre Many thanks once again. it works perfectly fine. Just a small question: is there any command to change the angle of the arrow heads?