# Plotting classical polymer model

Tags: graphics

I wonder how to plot a diagram like this[image]

I don't mean to duplicate this diagram, but can we possibly come up with a way to plot the polymer chain with as many monomers as we want, also, can we specify the each angle meanwhile?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you given it a try perhaps?

Comment: Have you seen `AnglePath[]`?

Comment: It needs to be built from graphics primitives as described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphics.html) and in related tutorials linked at the end of that page.  Skim through those pages, give it a try, and let us know where you got stuck.

Comment: @Johu, I'm not asking someone to plot this for me, I'm trying to get some clue where to start from. And thanks, `AnglePath[ ]` looks useful.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37207) or [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88197).

Comment: @J.M. That 3D spring stretch in the first link is particularly appealing to me!

Answer (score 3):

The basic steps will be:

- Construct the `list` of coordinates for where the "balls" will be. As J.M. said, [`AnglePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnglePath.html) will be useful
- Write a function `ball` for drawing a ball at given coordinates
- Write a function `link` for drawing a link between two coordinates
- `Map` the `ball` function over `list`
- `Apply` the `link` function at level `1` to `Partition[list, 2, 1]`.

References:

- [The structure of graphics](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphics.html), including the tutorial links at the end
- [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html), [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html), [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html), [`Disk`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Disk.html), [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line.html)